# copying a value from a byte[] to object's attributes

Tags: android, marshalling, unmarshalling

I'm looking to solve this situation:

I recive from a Socket (e.g. from a win based station) a Byte[], I know the memory address of this array and the structure. In this Byte[] i have values to fill the attributes of an object.

I'm looking for something like: 
unmarshall(targetObject,byte[]);

So how to create the object to be filled with the byte[]?
I will need to do also the reverse: package all the object's attributes in a byte[].

I read about the sum.misc.Unsafe but I found issues import this class in Android (in Java is working with some warning).

Thank you

Comment: The ObjectOutputStream/InputStream does de/serializes objects as byte[], not sure if you can communicate with other APIs except Java.

Comment: Do you know the packet structure...?

Comment: @Submersed yes I know. 
1)I will recreate all the structures like the server has.
2)The server will tell me the kind of structure the byte[] belong.
3)I get the byte[] and apply like attributes of the object.
(between me and server only the ID "type of the structure" and the values for fill the object)

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos yes, reading the byte[] from  the JAVA streams i created i always found additional bytes to describe the structure. Seems  there are no other way to build the byte[] that do it manually...